# Can I replace 'whom' with 'that'?

Tags: whom, that

Can I say
Mr. Smith is a teacher that I really like.
OR Mr. Smith is a teacher whom I really like.

Comment: Yes, with ascriptive predicative complements like the one in your example, the relativised element is mormally non-_wh_. In other words, do not use "who(m).

Answer (score 1):

both are correct, since "that" can also be used for persons

you can also say "Mr. Smith is the teacher I really like", removing "that/whom" and it would still be correct.